# classification theorem in a subset of R^2

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I need some very simple results of algebraic topology but I am not sure where I can find them without having to swallow the whole theory. What I want:

-An open bounded subset $A$ of $R^2$ is homeomorphic to a sphere iff it is connected and its complementary is connected (is it true? If not, I can assume that this subset is a closed $C^1$ manifold)

-Let $A'$ be another simply connected subset of $R^2$ that has Hausdorff distance one with $A$ (every point of $A$ is at distance $1$ from $A'$ and vice versa). Can the homeomorphism be contained in the space of all points at distance 1 (or 2, or any finite number) from $A$? In other words, the result below still holds if $R^2$ is replaced by an open subset?

Thanks

Is it still true if "homeomorphic" is replaced by "topologically equivalent"?

Comment: I don't understand. The Jordan curve theorem says that the complement of a circle in $\Bbb R^2$ is *disconnected*, not connected. And you can't embed a 2-sphere in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "topologically equivalent" if not "homeomorphic?"

Comment: I'm not talking of a circle, but of a disc, meaning the inside is filled. But if you are talking of Jordan's curve, let us put it like that: Is the bounded component of a Jordan's curve homeomorphic (or topologically equivalent) to an open disc?

Comment: Yes, this is part of the Jordan Curve Theorem.

Comment: Like I said I'm not an expert, but for me "topologically equivalent" means that the group of all the continuous loops contained either in the set or its complementary has the same structure than the same group for the disc.

Comment: That's not the standard definition of "topologically equivalent." I think you mean  that their fundamental groups are isomorphic, which is implied by homeomorphism.

Comment: @grumpy: Thanks, so the second part of the question is the following: If the Jordan curve stays at distance h from the disc boundary (i.e. the unit circle), do we have an homeomorphism that is the identity on all the points which are at distance (say) 2h from the circle? (with h small)

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement is not true, since we can take $A$ to be a line segment, which is not homeomorphic to a sphere of any dimension.

Comment: I edited the post with "open subset", but what I'm interested in is the topology equivalence, not so much the homeomorphism in itself.

Comment: by the way a segment is not a $C^1$ manifold